# How to resolve depedency between different versions

Tags: maven, version

I was exploring maven, currently using Ant. The application which we use here have different modules.
Now if I add dependencies to those how I can solve version conflict. Example module A has the dependecy of version1. while module B has the dependency of version2 now If someone need to work with both the module together than it will automatically resolve to version2 that is higher version.

Is there any internal behavior of maven or any command that I can use to resolve version conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Maven "solves" this problem by using the nearest declaration for transitives dependencies.

e.g.

A ->  X  -> externalLib 2.0
B -> externalLib 1.0

C -> A,B will result in using externalLib 1.0 since the declaration (over B) of 1.0 is nearer to C that over A and X
If they have the same distance the position within the POM file decides.

This is typically not the kind of "solution" you want. Since they might be incompatible it is better to choose a version manualle explicitely and declare this version in the pom of C

C -> externalLib 2.1

Note, if there is no version that is compatible to both X and B, there is no solution and Java does not support several versions of the same lib in one classloader. In this case you thould think of using OSGi or similar.

Answer (score 0):

this link provides solution to your problem
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html